# Dovecot unknown user

Tags: dovecot

I asked that question on stackoverflow, but was pointed to ask it here instead.
The original thread is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383926/dovecot-user-not-found).

I'm having problems setting up my mailserver.
I tried to send a testmail like this:
(Because it was pointed out in the comments: I'm sending this mail to myself. However I don't receive it.)

```
echo "Dies ist ein Test .." | mail -s "Testmail" test@example.net
```

However it never get's through.
My dovecote log tells me the following:

```
2013-05-05 12:55:18 dovecot: Info: Dovecot v1.2.15 starting up (core dumps disabled)
2013-05-05 12:55:38 auth(default): Info: passwd-file(test@example.net): unknown user
2013-05-05 12:55:38 auth(default): Info: passwd(test@example.net): unknown user
2013-05-05 12:55:38 auth(default): Info: passwd-file(root@example.net): unknown user
2013-05-05 12:55:38 auth(default): Info: passwd(root@example.net): unknown user
```

I'm quite puzzled, since the user does exist imo.
From my dovecote.conf:

```
userdb passwd-file {
    args = /var/mail/vhosts/example.net/passwd
}

passdb passwd-file {
    # File contains a list of usernames, one per line
    args = /var/mail/vhosts/example.net/shadow
}
```

(I have even removed the %d and replaced it with example.net, didn't work tough.)

Those files do exists and contain the test user entry.
From the file passwd:

```
test::5000:5000::/var/mail/vhosts/example.net/test
```

Comment: I thought Dovecot is a POP3/IMAP server (for *retrieving* mail). How does it have a role in your problem with *sending* mail?

Comment: I'm sending the mail to myself. I simply don't receive anything. As the log goes, the mail is returned to sender (root in this case), because reipient doesn'T exist. Then an other error is created, because the mail back fails, since root doesn't exist.